# Sync zoom level in quad view

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow

How can I sync the zoom level in all 3 perspectives in a quad view?

Currently, when I zoom in one of them (top ortho for instance) the other two are not zooming with it, resulting in an inconsistent setup. I'm used to all perspectives being in sync from other tools.

Answer (score 5):

In the view preferences (<kbd>N</kbd>), under Display, checking "Box" should do the trick:

[image]