# How to see object from multiple perspectives in real time

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a helmet, I have a reference image of the head from frontal view and side view, I would like to see the helmet overlapping both views of the head, and I want to be able to modify one view of the object and see the changes in the other view as well, something like a link between the two objects, the same way you would create a texture pattern.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/sync-zoom-level-in-quad-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *Quad View* mode in the 3D View, just go to *View > Area > Toggle Quad View* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) to activate.

To keep the views in sync you can toggle on the *Box* option under the <kbd>N</kbd> *3D View Sidebar > View > Quad View > Box*.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that sync option is a very nice feature, thanks :).

Comment: That is perfect!