# 2.82a Quad View: Sidebar Region Display "missing"?

Tags: interface

I'm trying to have a bit more control of the views while in Quad View (change view. rotate, etc...). I was reading that the controls for unlocking the views in Quad View were in the Display tab of the Sidebar Region - that is from the 2.82 docs. That does not seem to be the case for me. While in Quad View I press "N" and the only tabs available are Tool, View & Edit. Has the Display settings been moved recently. I've had a pretty good look around and don't see any options for unlocking the views. I've tried resetting to factory defaults and still no joy.

Googling brings up older articles pertaining to 2.7*.
Thanks!
Daf

Comment: Hello :). It seems to be moved under *View > Quad View* https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175471/

Comment: Thank you. It had indeed been moved to View > Quad View. Problem solved!