# Quad view with linked viewport transforms but separate shading

Tags: 3d-view

I'd like to reproduce Modo's quad view:

- 3 quadrants are orthogonal and wireframe, the 4th is perspective and shaded.
- The ortho views share center and zoom level while the perspective view is independent.

The inbuilt quad view shares shading between quadrants, splitting a single 3d viewport into 4 allows diff shading modes but the center and zoom levels are not shared...

EDIT: Added screenshot:
Note how the zoom level and viewport center is shared by the ortho views. Shading modes (and other visibility settings) are set per quadrant.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you could [edit] and add an image of the view you are wanting to reproduce? Many users here have probably not used modo.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/sync-zoom-level-in-quad-view as well as Quad View options in manual, there is Box option (aside from Lock one mentioned in the linked answer above with gif) which will sync zoom level